Getting error for startDestination gives error in Wear Navigation Compose with type safety
How to use Navigation library in Wear compose with type safety version. The SwipeDismissableNavHost's startDestination propety doesn't accept Any value like NavHost.
Used Dependency for wear navigation Compose:
androidx.wear.compose:compose-navigation:1.5.0-alpha04
Please find below code and error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination home is not a direct child of this NavGraph
Code:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
installSplashScreen()

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black)

setContent {
    WearAppIMSTheme {
        Scaffold(timeText = {
            TimeText(
                timeTextStyle = TimeTextDefaults.timeTextStyle(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground
                )
            )
        },
            content = {
                DemoApp(modifier = Modifier)
            })
    }
}
}
}

@Composable
fun DemoApp(modifier: Modifier) {

Box(
modifier = modifier
    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
) {
val navController = rememberSwipeDismissableNavController()


/**
 * NavHost Builds a navGraph to handle navigation, set the start destination to Home and
 * provide the navController which will control the navigation.
 */


SwipeDismissableNavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = ("home") // Getting Error: IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination home is not a direct child of this NavGraph
) {

    composable<Routes.Home> {
        Home(navigateToDetails = { aptDetails ->
            navController.navigate(Routes.AppointmentDetail(aptDetails))
        }, navigateToMySchedule = {
            navController.navigate(Routes.MySchedule)
        }, navigateToWaitingApts = {
            navController.navigate(Routes.WaitingForMe)
        })
    }

    composable<Routes.WaitingForMe> {
        WaitingForMe(onBackPress = {
            navController.popBackStack()
        })
    }

    composable<Routes.AppointmentDetail>(
        typeMap = mapOf(typeOf<ApptList>() to NavType.fromCustom<ApptList>())
    ) {
        val apptList = rememberSaveable {
            it.toRoute<Routes.AppointmentDetail>().apptDetail
        }
        AppointmentDetail(apptList, onBackPress = {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }, modifier)
    }

    composable<Routes.MySchedule> {

        MySchedule(onBackPress = {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }, modifier = Modifier,
            navigateToDetails = {
                navController.navigate(Routes.AppointmentDetail(it))
            })
    }
}

}

}


With type safe navigation you should set startDestination as Routes.Home or  startDestination = Routes.Home::class it's an object, or Routes.Home() if it's a class.
If you wish or it's mandatory to add a class as String route you can do it like this
startDestination = "${Routes.Home.javaClass.packageName}.Routes.Home"

for
@Serializable
sealed class Routes {

    @Serializable
    data object Home : Routes()
}


With SwipeDismissableNavHost's startDestination only accepts String property. I can't give object or class. Also, please note that, I am using wear navigation compose as mentioned in my above question

You can add it with package name if you wish to use overload with String startDestination.

This is also not working. Opens blank screen.
